# Windows 10 1809 cannot retain default browser after restart

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, domain

We are on a domain with Win10 1809 v.10.0.17763.720.  The original WIM file has Chrome set as the default browser.  But every time a system restarts, it reverts back to IE11.  I have checked the DefaultAppAssociation.xml and DefaultFileAssociation.xml and confirmed that Chrome is the default.  This has happened recently.  I have removed whatever Windows updates that were installed recently with no change.  So, when ever we open Chrome for the 1st time that day, we need to "Set as Default" every day. Any insight to this ?  Upgrading to 1903 for the 3000+ corporate systems is NOT an option right now (even though I have asked to take this route).

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault actually as you are on a domain with policies and such.... comments deleted....

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED...MDT pointed to older DefaultFileAssociation.xml and DefaultAppAssociation.xml files.  I updated them and Win10 now retains Chrome as default browser.